# How can I backup my WTP Server configuration?

Tags: eclipse, version-control, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

It's taken me a while to get my "**Server project**" (a Tomcat server) setup just the way I want it in my Eclipse workspace.  My process wasn't easy and included many errors.  With that, I think "*Gee, I should be able to save this project in CVS*", just like any other project.  Right?

I've checked the [WTP Tomcat FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ), but haven't found what I'm looking for.  I'm not sure if this is standard, or if a "best practice" exists - but I think it would be really handy!

If new developers come into our team, my laptop bursts into flames or I accidentally change my configuration; it would be great to just open the proper CVS version of this project.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should never have to do it and I would think that's bad practice. Ideally, you should be able to run update Project Configuration from m2eclipse and it should all work (except in some occasions having to setup facets)

Comment: I don't think that's a very helpful 'answer' , I have a very specific configuration of my server setup in Eclipse and I think it's reasonable to want to backup this configuration.  Care to walk me through or point me toward a _m2eclipse_ solution?